# Convexity of this function, the ordinary definition of convex functions took me a lot of time!

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, functional-inequalities

I have been struggling with this problem for about 2 days, I could prove that following function is convex using the definition of convex functions, but I need to prove its convexity using Bregman Distance.
so far I know that it is a Bregman Distance of another function, but I could not find that function. I appreciate any help, thanks.
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
 (x_1 -x_2) (\ln(x_1) -\ln(x_2))\, \,\,\,\mbox{ if} \,\,\,x \in R^2_{++} \\
 0                  \qquad       \qquad   \mbox{ if},\, x=0 \\
 +\infty     \qquad       \qquad                \mbox{ otherwise} \end{array} \right. $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : what is the Bregman distance of $x\ln x$ (linear functions are convex)?

Comment: the Bregman distance of $ x\ln (x)$ is 
$$ x\ln (x) -x\ln(y) -x+y$$

Comment: about Bregman Distance  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bregman_divergence

Comment: Yes. Let $D$ be the above bregman distance. $f(x,y) = D(x,y) + D(y,x) +...$

Comment: yes, I get it now, thanks a lot.